# Is it even possible to to add voices to this 2-part harmony?

Tags: harmony, voice-leading

Soprano: C-B-A-A-G (descending)

Bass: A-B-C (ascending), then down to D and up to G.

Can you even add tenor and alto without breaking the rules of harmony? It seems like it is impossible.

So are there ways to harmonize this?
I did try it with 3 voices but ended up with B-D-B on the second beat. This is not correct as a sixth interval is good, but we have a G chord without G and with two thirds.

You don't want to end up with B-E-B since you'll end up with a fifth.

Comment: "Harmony" is a very subjective term these days. Could you please be more specific as to what harmony rules you are referring to?

Comment: I would recommend adding a child's "Wow!", which for some reason harmonizes with anything, even [silence](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/q/blog/orchestra-seeks-child-who-shouted-wonder-filled-wow-at-end-of-concert-1.5128372)

Comment: Post notation! Are we supposed to guess the rhythm of the parts?

Answer (score 2):

I think B-D-B on the second beat shouldn't be disregarded too readily, but the implied harmony is rather E⁷ than G. This could be brought out even more by going full in with the leading tone:

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:C
K:C
%%score T1 Tn B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:Tn           clef=treble-8
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] c  B  A A  | G4
[V:Tn] E  ^G A c  | B4
[V:B]  A,,B,,C,D,,| G,,4
```

Comment: Shouldn't your middle voice be an octave higher?  Otherwise you start out with a 2nd inversion chord.

Comment: @ScottWallace yes, or rather, the bass should be an octave lower. Edited. Octave positions in ABC are always a trial&error for me...

Answer (score 2):

**Solutions**

Here are two 4-part solutions.

This one include `B-D-B` on the second beat.

```
X: 0
T: 4-Voice Solution with B-D-B on Beat 2
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: none
V:Soprano name="S"
V:Alto name="A"
V:Tenor clef=treble-8 name="T"
V:Bass clef=bass name="B"
[V:Soprano]cBAA|G4||
[V:Alto]AGA^F|D4||
[V:Tenor]edcc|B4||
[V:Bass]A,,B,,C,D,,|G,,4||
```

And this one, based on [@leftaroundabout's solution](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/85472/70803), includes `B-E-B` on the second beat.

```
X: 0
T: 4-Voice Solution with B-E-B on Beat 2
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: none
V:Soprano name="S"
V:Alto name="A"
V:Tenor clef=treble-8 name="T"
V:Bass clef=bass name="B"
[V:Soprano]cBAA|G4||
[V:Alto]EE_ED|_E4||
[V:Tenor]E^GAc|_B4||
[V:Bass]A,,B,,C,D,,|G,,4||
```

**Discussion**

As @Pyromonk indicated in the comments on the question:

> "Harmony" is a very subjective term these days. Could you please be more specific as to what harmony rules you are referring to?

"Harmony" has a variety of definitions. There's Modal harmony, Tonal harmony, Jazz/Rock harmony, Microtonal harmony, and probably others I'm not thinking of or don't know about. So the system you're using is key. However, I'm allowing that you're asking about Common Practice (ca. 1600 - 1900) harmony. So, major/minor Tonality.

@leftaroundabout is also spot-on to point out that a too-restrictive approach to the "allowed" chords can paint one into a corner.

However, you are correct that in a 3-voice texture, if you require the second beat to be a `G` chord, then you can't use `D`, because you're missing the root of the chord. Doubling the third isn't a problem, though. What is not allowed is doubling a leading tone. In this case, the third is not functioning as a leading tone, so can be doubled.

The `B-E-B` solution for beat 2 is also okay. Fifths are okay; they just aren't to be used consecutively. It would be okay to ascend from E to F, because parallel fourths (with the bass, in this case) are allowed.

Another 3-voice problem is beat 4 moving to beat 1. Let's allow the goal is to end on a `G` chord. In that case, "the rules" pretty much require `F#` on beat 4 to serve as the leading tone. But that results in three `G`s and no third in the chord. Allowed, but pretty stark.

Ultimately, I think four voices are actually easier to set here. The problem of 2-note chords can be solved in that way.